# How to use getproperty fast in Rational Functional Test v8.2

Tags: rft, rational-team-concert, ibm-rational

I am using getproperty to find the title of windows. There are numerous windows to detect. So my question is how we can make to execute this property fast.

```
WindowName = AssignWindow().GetProperty(".name")
```

As its taking 30 seconds to detect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance problems when accessing elements often occur due to bad object recognition. When you update the recognition properties of the AssignWindow object in the Object Map, are there some properties which are not matching properly? If all the properties are matching (also from the parent-objects), the performance of getProperty() should be quite good.

Answer (score 0):

If the logs and traces are disabled the GetProperty() API should not take more than a second. Is your question about the performance of this API or that because of numerous windows detecting the correct window is taking you 30 seconds?